# Django: request.POST contains only the last form in my formset

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

When I run `pprint(request.POST)`, it only returns the data of the last form of my formset. Why is this happening? Here is my code.

My `models.py`:

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    first_course = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, unique=False, max_length=30)
    first_course_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    second_course = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, unique=False, max_length=30)
    second_course_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    dessert = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, unique=False, max_length=30)
    dessert_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    drink = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, unique=False, max_length=30)
    drink_quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Date of order: {self.date}"
```

My `forms.py`:

```py
class DisabledOptionWidget(forms.Select):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        html_code = super(DisabledOptionWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs, renderer)
        html_code = html_code.replace(f'<option value=""', f'<option value="" disabled')
        return html_code


class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_course = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[("", 'Select a dish')] + [(f"{item}", item) for item in list(
    Menu.objects.values_list("first_course", flat=True))], widget=DisabledOptionWidget, required=False)
    first_course_quantity = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0)
    second_course = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[("", 'Select a dish')] + [(f"{item}", item) for item in list(
    Menu.objects.values_list("second_course", flat=True))], widget=DisabledOptionWidget, required=False)
    second_course_quantity = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0)
    dessert = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[("", 'Select a dish')] + [(f"{item}", item) for item in list(
    Menu.objects.values_list("dessert", flat=True))], widget=DisabledOptionWidget, required=False)
    dessert_quantity = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0)
    drink = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[("", 'Select a dish')] + [(f"{item}", item) for item in list(
    Menu.objects.values_list("drink", flat=True))], widget=DisabledOptionWidget, required=False)
    drink_quantity = forms.IntegerField(min_value=0)
    date = forms.DateField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = "__all__"

    def save(self, commit=True):
        if commit:
            order = Order.objects.create(
                date=self.cleaned_data['date'],
                first_course=self.cleaned_data['first_course'],
                first_course_quantity=self.cleaned_data['first_course_quantity'],
                second_course=self.cleaned_data['second_course'],
                second_course_quantity=self.cleaned_data['second_course_quantity'],
                dessert=self.cleaned_data['dessert'],
                dessert_quantity=self.cleaned_data['dessert_quantity'],
                drink=self.cleaned_data['drink'],
                drink_quantity=self.cleaned_data['drink_quantity']
            )
            return order
```

My **`views.py:`**

```py
class OrderView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = "myapp/order.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("order_success")
    formset_class = formset_factory(OrderForm, extra=5)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        days = self._get_days()
        formset = self.formset_class()

        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'formset': formset,
            'Monday': days[0],
            'Tuesday': days[1],
            'Wednesday': days[2],
            'Thursday': days[3],
            'Friday': days[4]
        })

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formset = self.formset_class(request.POST)

        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect(self.success_url)
        else:
            pprint(request.POST)
            return redirect('order')
```

My template looks like:

```
    {% for form in formset.forms %}
        {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}

            {% csrf_token %}
            <form id="first" class="off on" method='post'>
            <div class="main">

                <ul>
                    <li><h2 class="frst">First Course</h2></li>
                    <li><h2 class="qnt1">Quantity</h2></li>
                    <li><h2 class="fprc">Price</h2></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    {% render_field form.first_course id='f1_fc'  %}
                    {% render_field form.first_course_quantity id='f1_fcq' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                    <div class="sq" id='f1_fcp'></div>
                </ul><br>
                <ul>
                    <li><h2 class="tst">Second Course</h2></li>
                    <li><h2 class="qnt2">Quantity</h2></li>
                    <li><h2 class="prc">Price</h2></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    {% render_field form.second_course id='f1_sc'  %}
                    {% render_field form.second_course_quantity id='f1_scq' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                    <div class="sq" id='f1_scp'></div>
                </ul><br>
                <ul>
                    <li><h2>Dessert</h2></li>
                    <li><h2 class="qnt3">Quantity</h2></li>
                    <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    {% render_field form.dessert id='f1_des' %}
                    {% render_field form.dessert_quantity id='f1_des_q'  class="sq" type="number" %}
                    <div class="sq" id='f1_des_p' ></div>
                </ul><br>
                <ul>
                    <li><h2>Drinks</h2></li>
                    <li><h2 class="qnt4">Quantity</h2></li>
                    <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    {% render_field form.drink id='f1_dr' %}
                    {% render_field form.drink_quantity id='f1_dr_q'  class="sq" type="number" %}
                    <div class="sq" id='f1_dr_p' ></div>
                </ul>
            </div>
            {% render_field form.date id='f1_date' style="display:none"  %}
            </form>

        {% endif %}

        {% if forloop.counter == 2 %}
        
            <form id="second" class="off" method='post'>
                {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="main">
                <ul>
                    <li><h2 class="frst">First Course</h2></li>
                    <li><h2 class="qnt1">Quantity</h2></li>
                    <li><h2 class="fprc">Price</h2></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    {% render_field form.first_course id='f2_fc'  %}
                    {% render_field form.first_course_quantity id='f2_fcq' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                    <div class="sq" id='f2_fcp'></div>
                </ul><br>
                <ul>
                    <li><h2 class="tst">Second Course</h2></li>
                    <li><h2 class="qnt2">Quantity</h2></li>
                    <li><h2 class="prc">Price</h2></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    {% render_field form.second_course id='f2_sc'  %}
                    {% render_field form.second_course_quantity id='f2_scq'  class="sq" type="number" %}
                    <div class="sq" id='f2_scp' ></div>
                </ul><br>
                <ul>
                    <li><h2>Dessert</h2></li>
                    <li><h2 class="qnt3">Quantity</h2></li>
                    <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    {% render_field form.dessert id='f2_des'  %}
                    {% render_field form.dessert_quantity id='f2_des_q' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                    <div class="sq" id='f2_des_p'></div>
                </ul><br>
                <ul>
                    <li><h2>Drinks</h2></li>
                    <li><h2 class="qnt4">Quantity</h2></li>
                    <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    {% render_field form.drink id='f2_dr'  %}
                    {% render_field form.drink_quantity id='f2_dr_q' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                    <div class="sq" id='f2_dr_p'></div>
                </ul>
            </div>
            {% render_field form.date id='f2_date' style="display:none"  %}
            </form>

        {% endif %}

        {% if forloop.counter == 3 %}
        
            <form id="third" class="off" method='post'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="main">
                    <ul>
                        <li><h2 class="frst">First Course</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="qnt1">Quantity</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="fprc">Price</h2></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        {% render_field form.first_course id='f3_fc'  %}
                        {% render_field form.first_course_quantity id='f3_fcq' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                        <div class="sq" id='f3_fcp'></div>
                    </ul><br>
                    <ul>
                        <li><h2 class="tst">Second Course</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="qnt2">Quantity</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="prc">Price</h2></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        {% render_field form.second_course id='f3_sc'  %}
                        {% render_field form.second_course_quantity id='f3_scq' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                        <div class="sq" id='f3_scp'></div>
                    </ul><br>
                    <ul>
                        <li><h2>Dessert</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="qnt3">Quantity</h2></li>
                        <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        {% render_field form.dessert id='f3_des'  %}
                        {% render_field form.dessert_quantity id='f3_des_q' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                        <div class="sq" id='f3_des_p' ></div>
                    </ul><br>
                    <ul>
                        <li><h2>Drinks</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="qnt4">Quantity</h2></li>
                        <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        {% render_field form.drink id='f3_dr'  %}
                        {% render_field form.drink_quantity id='f3_dr_q' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                        <div class="sq" id='f3_dr_p' ></div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                {% render_field form.date id='f3_date' style="display:none"  %}
            </form>
        
        {% endif %}

        {% if forloop.counter == 4 %}
        
            <form id="four" class="off" method='post'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="main">
                    <ul>
                        <li><h2 class="frst">First Course</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="qnt1">Quantity</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="fprc">Price</h2></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        {% render_field form.first_course id="f4_fc"  %}
                        {% render_field form.first_course_quantity id="f4_fcq" class="sq"  type="number" %}
                        <div class="sq" id="f4_fcp"></div>
                    </ul><br>
                    <ul>
                        <li><h2 class="tst">Second Course</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="qnt2">Quantity</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="prc">Price</h2></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        {% render_field form.second_course id='f4_sc'  %}
                        {% render_field form.second_course_quantity id='f4_scq' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                        <div class="sq" id='f4_scp'></div>
                    </ul><br>
                    <ul>
                        <li><h2>Dessert</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="qnt3">Quantity</h2></li>
                        <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        {% render_field form.dessert id='f4_des'  %}
                        {% render_field form.dessert_quantity id='f4_des_q' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                        <div class="sq" id='f4_des_p'></div>
                    </ul><br>
                    <ul>
                        <li><h2>Drinks</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="qnt4">Quantity</h2></li>
                        <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        {% render_field form.drink id='f4_dr'  %}
                        {% render_field form.drink_quantity id='f4_dr_q' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                        <div class="sq" id='f4_dr_p' ></div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                {% render_field form.date id='f4_date' style="display:none"  %}
            </form>
        
        {% endif %}
        
        {% if forloop.counter == 5 %}
        
            <form id="five" class="off" method='post'>
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="main">
                    <ul>
                        <li><h2 class="frst">First Course</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="qnt1">Quantity</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="fprc">Price</h2></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        {% render_field form.first_course id='f5_fc'  %}
                        {% render_field form.first_course_quantity id='f5_fcq'  class="sq" type="number" %}
                        <div class="sq" id='f5_fcp' ></div>
                    </ul><br>
                    <ul>
                        <li><h2 class="tst">Second Course</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="qnt2">Quantity</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="prc">Price</h2></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        {% render_field form.second_course id='f5_sc'  %}
                        {% render_field form.second_course_quantity id='f5_scq' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                        <div class="sq" id='f5_scp'></div>
                    </ul><br>
                    <ul>
                        <li><h2>Dessert</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="qnt3">Quantity</h2></li>
                        <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        {% render_field form.dessert id='f5_des'  %}
                        {% render_field form.dessert_quantity id='f5_des_q' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                        <div class="sq" id='f5_des_p'></div>
                    </ul><br>
                    <ul>
                        <li><h2>Drinks</h2></li>
                        <li><h2 class="qnt4">Quantity</h2></li>
                        <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        {% render_field form.drink id='f5_dr'  %}
                        {% render_field form.drink_quantity id='f5_dr_q' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                        <div class="sq" id='f5_dr_p'></div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                {% render_field form.date id='f5_date' style="display:none"  %}
            </form>

        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}    
    
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="b1" onclick="backBtn()" id="back" style="visibility: hidden;">Back</button>
        <button class="b1" onclick="nextBtn()" id="next"><a href='#'>Next</a></button>
    </div>
    
    <script src="{% static 'myapp/js/order.js' %}"></script>
    <script>
        let date_1 = '{{ Monday }}';
        let date_2 = '{{ Tuesday }}';
        let date_3 = '{{ Wednesday }}';
        let date_4 = '{{ Thursday }}';
        let date_5 = '{{ Friday }}';
        $('#f1_date').val(date_1);
        $('#f2_date').val(date_2);
        $('#f3_date').val(date_3);
        $('#f4_date').val(date_4);
        $('#f5_date').val(date_5);
</script>
```

Comment: How does the template look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are directly rendering the fields for only the first form in the formset in your template. `formset.forms.0.first_course`

That is why you are facing this issue.

You need to put in a `for loop` and change your `render_field`

You should change your template to something like this:

```
 <form id="first" class="off on" method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}

    {% for form in formset.forms %}
    <div class="main">
        <ul>
            <li><h2 class="frst">First Course</h2></li>
            <li><h2 class="qnt1">Quantity</h2></li>
            <li><h2 class="fprc">Price</h2></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            {% render_field form.first_course id='f1_fc'  %}
            {% render_field form.first_course_quantity id='f1_fcq' class="sq"  type="number" %}
            <div class="sq" id='f1_fcp'></div>
        </ul><br>
        ... Other form fields
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </form> ...other code...
{% render_field formset.forms.0.date id='f1_date' style="display:none"  %}
<script>
        let date_1 = '{{ Monday }}';
        $('#f1_date').val(date_1);
</script>
```

This way it will iterate and create all the entire formset

Comment: Thank you! It's my error because I badly explained. By writing "... other code ..." I meant "like that for the rest of forms". I'll try your recommendations and I hope It will work.

Comment: I've changed my template code, but I've still the same problem. Could you check It pls ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something like that:

```
<form method='POST' id='main_form'>
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% for form in formset.forms %}
            {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
        
                <div id="first" class="off on" method='post'>
                    <div class="main">

                        <ul>
                            <li><h2 class="frst">First Course</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="qnt1">Quantity</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="fprc">Price</h2></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {% render_field form.first_course id='f1_fc'  %}
                            {% render_field form.first_course_quantity id='f1_fcq' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                            <div class="sq" id='f1_fcp'></div>
                        </ul><br>
                        <ul>
                            <li><h2 class="tst">Second Course</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="qnt2">Quantity</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="prc">Price</h2></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {% render_field form.second_course id='f1_sc'  %}
                            {% render_field form.second_course_quantity id='f1_scq' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                            <div class="sq" id='f1_scp'></div>
                        </ul><br>
                        <ul>
                            <li><h2>Dessert</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="qnt3">Quantity</h2></li>
                            <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {% render_field form.dessert id='f1_des' %}
                            {% render_field form.dessert_quantity id='f1_des_q'  class="sq" type="number" %}
                            <div class="sq" id='f1_des_p' ></div>
                        </ul><br>
                        <ul>
                            <li><h2>Drinks</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="qnt4">Quantity</h2></li>
                            <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {% render_field form.drink id='f1_dr' %}
                            {% render_field form.drink_quantity id='f1_dr_q'  class="sq" type="number" %}
                            <div class="sq" id='f1_dr_p' ></div>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    {% render_field form.date id='f1_date' style="display:none"  %}
                </div>
        
            {% endif %}
        
            {% if forloop.counter == 2 %}
        
                <div id="second" class="off" method='post'>
                
                    <div class="main">
                        <ul>
                            <li><h2 class="frst">First Course</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="qnt1">Quantity</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="fprc">Price</h2></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {% render_field form.first_course id='f2_fc'  %}
                            {% render_field form.first_course_quantity id='f2_fcq' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                            <div class="sq" id='f2_fcp'></div>
                        </ul><br>
                        <ul>
                            <li><h2 class="tst">Second Course</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="qnt2">Quantity</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="prc">Price</h2></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {% render_field form.second_course id='f2_sc'  %}
                            {% render_field form.second_course_quantity id='f2_scq'  class="sq" type="number" %}
                            <div class="sq" id='f2_scp' ></div>
                        </ul><br>
                        <ul>
                            <li><h2>Dessert</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="qnt3">Quantity</h2></li>
                            <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {% render_field form.dessert id='f2_des'  %}
                            {% render_field form.dessert_quantity id='f2_des_q' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                            <div class="sq" id='f2_des_p'></div>
                        </ul><br>
                        <ul>
                            <li><h2>Drinks</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="qnt4">Quantity</h2></li>
                            <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {% render_field form.drink id='f2_dr'  %}
                            {% render_field form.drink_quantity id='f2_dr_q' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                            <div class="sq" id='f2_dr_p'></div>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    {% render_field form.date id='f2_date' style="display:none"  %}
                </div>
        
            {% endif %}
        
            {% if forloop.counter == 3 %}
        
                <div id="third" class="off" method='post'>
                
                    <div class="main">
                        <ul>
                            <li><h2 class="frst">First Course</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="qnt1">Quantity</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="fprc">Price</h2></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {% render_field form.first_course id='f3_fc'  %}
                            {% render_field form.first_course_quantity id='f3_fcq' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                            <div class="sq" id='f3_fcp'></div>
                        </ul><br>
                        <ul>
                            <li><h2 class="tst">Second Course</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="qnt2">Quantity</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="prc">Price</h2></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {% render_field form.second_course id='f3_sc'  %}
                            {% render_field form.second_course_quantity id='f3_scq' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                            <div class="sq" id='f3_scp'></div>
                        </ul><br>
                        <ul>
                            <li><h2>Dessert</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="qnt3">Quantity</h2></li>
                            <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {% render_field form.dessert id='f3_des'  %}
                            {% render_field form.dessert_quantity id='f3_des_q' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                            <div class="sq" id='f3_des_p' ></div>
                        </ul><br>
                        <ul>
                            <li><h2>Drinks</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="qnt4">Quantity</h2></li>
                            <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {% render_field form.drink id='f3_dr'  %}
                            {% render_field form.drink_quantity id='f3_dr_q' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                            <div class="sq" id='f3_dr_p' ></div>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    {% render_field form.date id='f3_date' style="display:none"  %}
                </div>
        
            {% endif %}
        
            {% if forloop.counter == 4 %}
        
                <div id="four" class="off" method='post'>
                
                    <div class="main">
                        <ul>
                            <li><h2 class="frst">First Course</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="qnt1">Quantity</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="fprc">Price</h2></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {% render_field form.first_course id="f4_fc"  %}
                            {% render_field form.first_course_quantity id="f4_fcq" class="sq"  type="number" %}
                            <div class="sq" id="f4_fcp"></div>
                        </ul><br>
                        <ul>
                            <li><h2 class="tst">Second Course</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="qnt2">Quantity</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="prc">Price</h2></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {% render_field form.second_course id='f4_sc'  %}
                            {% render_field form.second_course_quantity id='f4_scq' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                            <div class="sq" id='f4_scp'></div>
                        </ul><br>
                        <ul>
                            <li><h2>Dessert</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="qnt3">Quantity</h2></li>
                            <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {% render_field form.dessert id='f4_des'  %}
                            {% render_field form.dessert_quantity id='f4_des_q' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                            <div class="sq" id='f4_des_p'></div>
                        </ul><br>
                        <ul>
                            <li><h2>Drinks</h2></li>
                            <li><h2 class="qnt4">Quantity</h2></li>
                            <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {% render_field form.drink id='f4_dr'  %}
                            {% render_field form.drink_quantity id='f4_dr_q' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                                <div class="sq" id='f4_dr_p' ></div>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        {% render_field form.date id='f4_date' style="display:none"  %}
                    </div>

                {% endif %}
            
                {% if forloop.counter == 5 %}
            
                    <div id="five" class="off" method='post'>
                        <div class="main">
                            <ul>
                                <li><h2 class="frst">First Course</h2></li>
                                <li><h2 class="qnt1">Quantity</h2></li>
                                <li><h2 class="fprc">Price</h2></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                {% render_field form.first_course id='f5_fc'  %}
                                {% render_field form.first_course_quantity id='f5_fcq'  class="sq" type="number" %}
                                <div class="sq" id='f5_fcp' ></div>
                            </ul><br>
                            <ul>
                                <li><h2 class="tst">Second Course</h2></li>
                                <li><h2 class="qnt2">Quantity</h2></li>
                                <li><h2 class="prc">Price</h2></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                {% render_field form.second_course id='f5_sc'  %}
                                {% render_field form.second_course_quantity id='f5_scq' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                                <div class="sq" id='f5_scp'></div>
                            </ul><br>
                            <ul>
                                <li><h2>Dessert</h2></li>
                                <li><h2 class="qnt3">Quantity</h2></li>
                                <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                {% render_field form.dessert id='f5_des'  %}
                                {% render_field form.dessert_quantity id='f5_des_q' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                                <div class="sq" id='f5_des_p'></div>
                            </ul><br>
                            <ul>
                                <li><h2>Drinks</h2></li>
                                <li><h2 class="qnt4">Quantity</h2></li>
                                <li><h2>Price</h2></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                {% render_field form.drink id='f5_dr'  %}
                                {% render_field form.drink_quantity id='f5_dr_q' class="sq"  type="number" %}
                                <div class="sq" id='f5_dr_p'></div>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        {% render_field form.date id='f5_date' style="display:none"  %}
                    </div>
            
                {% endif %}
            
            {% endfor %}    
            
            <div class="buttons">
                <button class="b1" onclick="backBtn()" id="back" style="visibility: hidden;">Back</button>
                <button class="b1" onclick="nextBtn()" id="next"><a href='#'>Next</a></button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).